# Need solution for when Exporting CSV, getting the current page's HTML code also in the excel file

Tags: php, html, excel, csv, export-to-csv

**This is the `HTML` code for the `Export` button:**

```
<form method="post" name="download_csv" class="pull-right" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <button type="submit" name="Export" class="btn btn-success" >Export to excel</button>
</form>
```

**This is the `PHP` code for `Exporting data` to `CSV`:**

```
// DB data Export to Excel 
if(isset($_POST['Export'])){
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset= utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= data.csv');
    $output= fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('Id','Name','Address', 'Contact no.','Email'));
    $query = "Select id,name,address,contact,emailcontact from addresses where user_id='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER By id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

But When i'm clicking on the `Export to excel` button, It exports the `correct data` with the `current page's` `html code`. I don't know why is that happening. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what your probelm is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem is resolved by adding:
`exit();` at the end of my `PHP` script.

Now it should be:

```
`// DB data Export to Excel 
if(isset($_POST['Export'])){
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset= utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= data.csv');
    $output= fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('Id','Name','Address', 'Contact no.','Email'));
    $query = "Select id,name,address,contact,emailcontact from addresses where user_id='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER By id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
exit();
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your form action is pointed to the same script. You should either do a conditional check to avoid that in the same script  or simply change the action url.

Comment: *"You should either do a conditional check"* - They're already using one; `if(isset($_POST['Export'])){...}`.

Comment: He should put the other parts of the script into the else part of statement.